# Shadowbox set background color

Tags: color, boxes, shadowbox

I am trying to set a background color for a shadowbox, as shown in this example, but have not managed to do so. Preferably I'd like to use this yellow color.
[image: Shadowbox]
Maybe someone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Please post the `MWE` of what you tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you expect like this?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\@shadowbox#1{%
  \setbox\@fancybox\hbox{\fcolorbox{black}{yellow!15}{#1}}%
  \leavevmode\vbox{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \dimen@=\shadowsize
    \advance\dimen@ .5\fboxrule
    \hbox{\copy\@fancybox\kern-.5\fboxrule\lower\shadowsize\hbox{%
      \vrule \@height\ht\@fancybox \@depth\dp\@fancybox \@width\dimen@}}%
    \vskip-\dimen@
    \moveright\shadowsize\vbox{%
      \hrule \@width\wd\@fancybox \@height\dimen@}}}
\makeatother

\shadowbox{%
\vbox{\lipsum[1-2]}
}


\end{document}
```

[image]

But `tcolorbox` is one of the other best option

Comment: Thank You! That is quite close to what I am looking for. Would it be possible to add a black border around the box.

Comment: Do you mean all four sides surrounded by a black frame?

Comment: Yes exactly, thats what I meant.

Comment: Please check the updated suggestion, just changed from `\colorbox` to `\fcolorbox`

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! Thank You so much! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code. Read the explanation from the comments in the code.

By the way if you increase the 10 to a higher number the yellow intensity increases.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % For math formatting
\usepackage{xcolor}   % To define colors
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} % To create colored boxes

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    colframe=yellow!50!black,
    hbox,
    on line
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}
\(
A \cap B = B \cap A
\)
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you quick answer. While I am already aware of the package tcolorbox I was specifically looking for the shadowbox and a way to change its color.